# issues with selecting last child in ie8 css3

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8, responsive-design

I make the responsive grid using percentage.
i'm using this

```
[class*=col-] + [class*=col-]:last-child{margin-right:0}
```

for find and replace the last column margin with 0, so that i have a issue with these pseudo elements, Any help on this !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IE8 does not support `:last-child`. It does support `:first-child`, but not `:last-child`.

This is because IE8 was designed to support CSS2.1: `:first-child` is in the CSS2.1 spec, but `:last-child` was only in the CSS3 spec.

In many cases, the best solution to this problem if you need to support IE8 is to re-factor your layout such that you use `:first-child` instead of `:last-child`.

This option is a good solution in a lot of cases, and for supporting IE8 without any hacks, it is the best way, but it obviously isn't suitable in all cases (otherwise they wouldn't have needed to invent `:last-child` at all). You haven't given enough information about your code for me to know whether it would be an option for you, but if it is, that's what I recommend.

Another option is to use the old fall-back solution and just add a class to the appropriate element, and style the class instead of the pseudo-selector. And old-school answer, but it will work.

Moving onto how to support IE8 but still use `:last-child`. There are ways of doing this, but they involve using Javascript polyfills. There are two scripts I know of that should do the trick for you:

- [Selectivizr](http://selectivizr.com/)
- [IE9.js](https://code.google.com/p/ie7-js/)

Of these, Selectivizr is newer piece of software, and only affects CSS selectors, whereas IE9.js is older, and attempts to patch numerous bugs, holes and missing features in various versions of IE. Both should do the trick for you; try them and see.

Hope that helps.